# Printing object hex value instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

Using python 3.5.

When my code below prints out `bs.parse()` it shows the hex value of the object instead of the value of `bs.parse`.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website_spider"

    site_search_url = 'website.com'

    website_base = 'http://www.websitenew.com/search?id=site:'
    start_urls = [website_base + site_search_url]
    def parse(self, response):
        website_result_list = []
        website_result_page = []

        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = 'a.sb_pagN ::attr(href)'
        next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
        headers={'referer':self.start_urls}
            )
            website_result_page.append(response.urljoin(next_page)) 

        #create LIST into SET to remove duplicates then change SET back to LIST.
        set(website_result_page)
        list(website_result_page)

        for brp in website_result_page:   
            return("printing brp: " + brp)

bs = BrickSetSpider()
print(bs.parse('200'))
```

returns:
`<generator object BrickSetSpider.parse at 0x7f6f609c8f10>`

Comment: Your `parse()` method is a generator function because it uses `yield`, so what you're see is correct. If you want to see the values it's yielding, usie it in a `for` loop to see each value, convert it to a list (i.e. `results = bs.parse('200')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just using the generic print function for objects. The hex value is the memory address of the object. Since the object is a generator, you can try casting it to a list first

```
print(list(bs.parse('200')))
```